# How to get y-axis starting from 0 (to see value difference from start to end) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting total no. of step (y-axis) vs. date and time (x-axis) in datetime format in matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data['datetime'], data['step'], color="orange")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
```

And the output example is:

[image]

In this case, suppose that in the beginning of the day, step counter start from around 8000 step, and at the end of the day it shows ~32000 steps. My question is, is it possible to plot with firstly change the y-axis starting number to 0? (other than creating a new column on the data frame, so that this graph y-axis would start from 0 to around 20.000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(data['datetime'], data['step']-data['step'].min(), color="orange")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyplot.axis()` method

```
plt.axis([0, x_limit, 0, y_limit])
```

If you specifically want to limit your `x-axis` or `y-axis`. You can use

```
pyplot.xlim(x_min, x_max)
pylpot.ylim(y_min, y_max)
```